# Packetsize in Gamepsparks Realtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, gamesparks

My packet in gamesparks contains:

```
Two vector2: 8bytes x 2 = 16bytes
key values with vector 2 = 8bytes
peerid present in packet = 4bytes
opCode present in packet = 4bytes

Total = 32bytes.
```

However my packet size is a little big bigger than this. Am i missing something in the packet that i should account for ?

Comment: r u able to solve this problem? I am having a problem in it.

Comment: Yes the packet includes some data by default used in transfer of packets i suppose. Gamesparks devs confirmed this on their forum.